# HTAccess routing certain pages to other domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, router

Hello i like to reroute certain pages to another domain. I like to do a post/get request to http://example.com/get.php?username=123&password=123&type=abc and route it to http://example2.com/get.php?username=123&password=123&type=abc.

I have 4 of these pages i like to re-route to another domain, i dont want to reroute all data - because on the first domain i have a website running and a api. So i only want to route certain pages.

I can rewrite my urls like i do already for the api to have nice url's - but i dont know how to get the above to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this:

```
# Rewrite to other domain
RewriteRule ^player_api.* http://example2.com:25461%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^panel_api.* http://example2.com:25461%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^xmltv.* http://example2.com:25461%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^get.* http://example2.com:25461%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,QSA]
```

This simply does a 302 found, but it works. Now i use a shorter domain - and my own domain to forward the requests.